Help - New user wishing to post University Survey
I'm a Uni student who is currently conducting research into determinants of cryptocurrency investment behaviour. I have a 10-15min survey that I'd like to get responses from people who are trading in cryptocurrency.
Before I post it and post the link, I just want to confirm that these sorts of posts are acceptable. I'm new to stack overflow so I couldn't work out how to message the Mod's.
The survey also has an option to enter a prize draw at the end to win crypto of your choosing to a certain value.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/advertising

Thank you for asking about this first instead of just posting it, as most people did in the past. Unfortunately, your question is off-topic and could even be considered spam. Here are some relevant references on Meta Stack Exchange:

Is it allowed to ask developers to complete a scientific survey on Stack Overflow?
Are research survey questionnaires spam on Stack Exchange sites?
Are research survey questions expected to be handled with close votes?

We're not a discussion forum, the tour says what we are:

With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about technologies supporting the Bitcoin currency in the past, present, or future.


thank you for your question. As Glorfindel already explained, that sort of content does not fit our scope. However, I'd like to suggest another online community that might fit better: reddit.com/r/bitcoin has 1.4m subscribers and allows this sort of survey. You may also want to check out reddit.com/r/bitcoinmarkets!
